# VPC maximum size is more than /16 in ipv4?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just added another CIDR with /16 ip addresses to my VPC ipv4. How is this possible. Is there not a maximum of /16 like described here?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/how-it-works.html#VPC_Sizing

[image]

Comment: This is a network concept called [subnetting](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/network-layer/what-is-a-subnet/). A VPC in AWS can have multiple subnets.

Comment: Suspect the doc is misleading. The [Manage IPv4 CIDR blocks for a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/configure-your-vpc.html) docs appear to show an example of a single VPC with multiple /16 CIDRs (10.0.0.0/16 and 10.2.0.0/16).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum size of any single IPV4 network in a AWS VPC is /16. That is 256*256 (65,536 IP addresses).
As per your config, your first network is 172.31.0.0/16

However, you can have additional networks in your VPC, as you have with your second network in you config (172.32.0.0/16).

(The number of such additional networks is limited to 5 - however this is adjustable by contacting the AWS support staff)